# How to trigger a onmousedown event manually from javascript (not jquery) on a empty td tag

Tags: javascript

I want to trigger a ommousedown event on a empty td tag using java script but not using jquery.
Any suggestions please

Comment: Have you tried anything yet..?

Comment: This question is a generic version of your specific one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript

Comment: function simulateClick(){                                  var event = new MouseEvent('onmousedown',                       { 'view': window, 'bubbles': true, 'cancelable': true });         var cb = document.getElementById('x');                cb.dispatchEvent(event); }                                        This is the code i have tried result is uncaught exception: [Exception... "Cannot convert WrappedNative to function" nsresult: "0x8057000d (NS_ERROR_XPC_CANT_CONVERT_WN_TO_FUN)"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I threw together a CodePen demo for you:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lrAxp

```
var element = document.getElementById('testButton');
if(document.createEvent)
{
  element.dispatchEvent(new Event('mousedown'));
}
else{
  // Internet Explorer (I think)
 element.fireEvent("onmousedown", event); 
}
```

You can also check out this SO post for more info: [How to trigger event in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript)

Comment: is it possible on a empty td tag with id dummy ?

Comment: I had problems with dispatching `new Event("mousedown")`. It wasn't being caught in my event handler. 
But if I dispatched `new MouseEvent("mousedown")` then it worked.

Comment: mousedown is undefined regardless of whether you use Event or MouseEvent. I don't know if it was simply removed from javascript but it now will break anything you try to use it in e.g. canvasElem.dispatchEvent(new Event('mousedown', {pageX: 264, pageY: 267}))

Comment: It doesn't work for me (Chrome v.106), but the accepted solution from this thread worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025165/simulating-a-mousedown-click-mouseup-sequence-in-tampermonkey

Answer (score 3):

This dispatches mousedown event on every empty td cell (on modern browsers):

```
var emptyTableCells = document.querySelectorAll("td:empty");
var mousedown = new Event('mousedown');
[].forEach.call(emptyTableCells, function(elem) {
   elem.dispatchEvent(mousedown);
});
```

Comment: is it possible on a empty td tag with id dummy ?

Answer (score -5):

If you just want something simple you can also use the [HTMLElement's click function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click):

```
var td = document.getElementsByTagName('td')[0];

td.onclick = function(){
    alert('!');
}

td.click();
```

Here's a fiddle that shows it in action: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PUDMu/1/)