# Simulating a mousedown, click, mouseup sequence in Tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

I would like to simulate a whole click not just

```
document.getElementsByClassName()[0].click();
```

How do I do that?  Search results all seem to be about handling such events, not triggering them.

Comment: you can use document.createEvent("MouseEvents") to simulate a click.

Comment: I thought this was only for things such as scroll wheel

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createEvent#Triggering_built-in_events

Comment: I dont understand how its simulating a whole mouse click without mousedown or mouseup =/ I dont know if what im trying to do is pointless or im just going about it the wrong way, basically I have a button that only works on mouseup.

Comment: well, type in the above code can be mouseup, mouseover, mousemove, or mouseout. the advantage there is that it (ideally) hits inline events (elm.onmouseup()), jQuery events ($(elm).trigger), and addEventListener-based events ( elm.dispatchEvent ) in one swoop. or, you can hit one the above event kinds manually without createEvent, whatever works...

Comment: Woo!!! The mozilla dev site did it for me. The key for me was: `var simMousedownEvent = new MouseEvent('mousedown', {
    'view': window,
    'bubbles': true,
    'cancelable': true
  });


$(“input.myelement”)[0].dispatchEvent(simMousedownEvent)` The [0] is needed to convert from jQuery object to native JS DOM object.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Send mouse events. Like so:

```
//--- Get the first link that has "stackoverflow" in its URL.
var targetNode = document.querySelector ("a[href*='stackoverflow']");
if (targetNode) {
    //--- Simulate a natural mouse-click sequence.
    triggerMouseEvent (targetNode, "mouseover");
    triggerMouseEvent (targetNode, "mousedown");
    triggerMouseEvent (targetNode, "mouseup");
    triggerMouseEvent (targetNode, "click");
}
else
    console.log ("*** Target node not found!");

function triggerMouseEvent (node, eventType) {
    var clickEvent = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent (eventType, true, true);
    node.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```

---

That works if the web page is statically loaded.  If the **web page is AJAX-driven**, use a technique as in:

- ["Normal" button-clicking approaches are not working in Greasemonkey script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511381/normal-button-clicking-approaches-are-not-working-in-greasemonkey-script)
- [Choosing and activating the right controls on an AJAX-driven site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048223/choosing-and-activating-the-right-controls-on-an-ajax-driven-site)

---

**Beware:**
The question code has an error.  You need to pass a class name to that function. Like so:

```
document.getElementsByClassName ("SomeClassName")[0].click();
```

Comment: You were not right in the sequence of native event firing. Click event is fired *after* mouseup. In case of double click the sequence is: mousedown, mouseup, click, mousedown, mouseup, click, dblclick. Be aware when relying on click event there is no builtin mechanism to distinguish between single and double clicks. I've suggested an edit of your answer. I hope you feel comfort with that.

Comment: As far as I know this behavior isn't very new. Up/down are basic events fired immediately and *click* or *drag* are composed when other conditions are matching. *mouseup* within the same Element the latest *mousedown* event has been targeted to is considered as click, likewise *mousemove* over a distance treshold while button is held as drag (when draggeble), similary *select*. Since *mouseup* is a hard fact while *click* is open to interpretation subsequently, this order should also be the expectable one.

Comment: Your code works perfect even when another methods fails! But please, can you add some code to simulate **Shift** Click?

Comment: @jsv, See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28895866/shift-mouse-click-trigger) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent), or open a new question if you need to.  Any new question should have an MCVE or link to a target page since the approach can differ based on the page and your end goal.

Comment: @BrockAdams, so I posted it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35173988). Hope it is not too wordy!

Comment: Firing mouse events doesn't seem to make the browser actually do things. It connects up to javascript listeners on those events, but things handled in the browser don't happen. Specifically, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/52208673/864696 . Mouseup event lost because of cross domain iframe; dispatching a new mouse event, even inside the iframe, doesn't make the mouse stop moving the insertion point in the textbox.

Comment: @RossPresser, javascript can't fire "trusted" events nor events on browser "Chrome" elements.  TM and  GM could provide some of that capability but currently do not.  Your question looks to be about a strange edge case and possible bug.

Comment: @BrockAdams - thanks for looking. It certainly is strange, and it happens only in Chromium based browsers. The linked Chromium bug had an answer that seemed to indicate they chose this behavior in order to support an edge case in Google Maps... anyway, very off topic for this question, so I'll stop here.

Comment: Warning: Many methods used with `createEvent`, such as `initCustomEvent`, are `deprecated`. Use event constructors instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent

Answer (score 22):

I improved [Brock's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24026594/979621) a little after it worked as expected for me.

Definition:

```
function simulateMouseClick(targetNode) {
    function triggerMouseEvent(targetNode, eventType) {
        var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        clickEvent.initEvent(eventType, true, true);
        targetNode.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
    }
    ["mouseover", "mousedown", "mouseup", "click"].forEach(function(eventType) { 
        triggerMouseEvent(targetNode, eventType);
    });
}
```

Calling examples:

```
simulateMouseClick(document);

simulateMouseClick(document.querySelector("a[href*='stackoverflow']"));
```

Answer (score 8):

Bit Optimized

```
function fireMouseEvents( query, eventNames ){
    var element = document.querySelector(query);
    if(element && eventNames && eventNames.length){
        for(var index in eventNames){
            var eventName = eventNames[index];
            if(element.fireEvent ){
                element.fireEvent( 'on' + eventName );     
            } else {   
                var eventObject = document.createEvent( 'MouseEvents' );
                eventObject.initEvent( eventName, true, false );
                element.dispatchEvent(eventObject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You would fire like this

```
fireMouseEvents("a[href*='stackoverflow']",['mouseover','mousedown','mouseup','click']);
```