# shift mouse click trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-events

I can trigger click event on `element selector` using `trigger`

```
$('element selector').trigger('click')
```

Is it possible to trigger shift click. I mean <kbd>shift</kbd> + left mouse click.

Comment: you mean do you want to programically create  a shift+mouse click ?

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV exactly

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try

```
var shiftClick = jQuery.Event("click");
shiftClick.shiftKey = true;

$("element selector").click(function(event) {
    if (event.shiftKey) {
       alert("Shift key is pressed");
    }
    else {
       alert('No shift hey');
    }
});

$("element selector").trigger(shiftClick);
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/d9ucj4os/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can check **[event.shiftKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/shiftKey)** boolean propery.

```
$("element selector").click(function(event) {
    if (event.shiftKey) {
       alert("Shift key is pressed");
    } 
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/63u5sbsb/)**

Comment: thank you, but I need `trigger` not `handler`. Trigger is something that simulates shift click  but not handle it.