# Simulate shift-mouseclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to somehow simulate Shift+Click?

This code works quite well, but currently, without shift:

```
//--- Get the first link that has "stackoverflow" in its URL.
var targetNode = document.querySelector ("a[href*='stackoverflow']");
if (targetNode) {
    //--- Simulate a natural mouse-click sequence.
    triggerMouseEvent (targetNode, "mouseover");
    triggerMouseEvent (targetNode, "mousedown");
    triggerMouseEvent (targetNode, "mouseup");
    triggerMouseEvent (targetNode, "click");
}

function triggerMouseEvent (node, eventType) {
    var clickEvent = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent (eventType, true, true);
    node.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update: If you want to trigger shift+click event, you can see this post**

**[shift mouse click trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28895866/shift-mouse-click-trigger)**

If you want to simulate shift+click, then you should use initMouseEvent instead of initEvent. Check the following fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/zqdftehw/2/

References:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/initMouseEvent
http://marcgrabanski.com/simulating-mouse-click-events-in-javascript/

If you want to know whether shift key is pressed or not, then the following will work,

```
<div id="test"></div>

<script>
  document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function( event ) {
    if (event.shiftKey) {
        console.log('shift pressed');
    } else {
        console.log('shift not pressed');
    }
  }, false);
</script>
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/click

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zqdftehw/1/

**Note: Both initEvent and initMouseEvent are deprecated, so you might want to use jQuery solution provided in the other stack overflow answer ([link mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28895866/shift-mouse-click-trigger)) to be on safer side.**

Comment: The problem with jQuery method you mentioned, is that it doesn't work in some cases. Sometimes it is need to reproduce the whole sequence: mouseover, mousedown, mouseup, click.