# Why element.click() not working in Cefsharp?

Tags: c#, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, cefsharp

I try to execute below script in **Cefsharp** to click on a DIV element, and not working.

```
private static string ClickUnreads = @"(function() {
                                        let chatsEl = document.querySelectorAll('.infinite-list-item');
                                        for (let x = 0; x < chatsEl.length; x++) {
                                            let unread = chatsEl[x].getElementsByClassName('unread');
                                            if (unread.length > 0) {
                                                chatsEl[x].click();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    })();";

public void ClickUnreads()
{
    WebBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync(ClickUnreads);
}
```

I found similar threads here that have problem similar to mine, but none of it's answer working.

I wanna use **Selenium** based solution, like I did in Java, but I need the browser to be embedded inside my app, and I can't use Headless browser, because the site which I'm trying to automate requires QR code authentication.

Is it possible to use **Chromium web driver** to control **Cefsharp**? If possible, anybody can shed a light for me? (show me the link of it).

Below is my code in Java, using Chrome web driver, and it works like charm

```
while (true) {
    List<WebElement> chatItems = chatsList.findElements(By.className("infinite-list-item"));
    for (WebElement el : chatItems) {
        WebElement unread = el.findElement(By.className("unread"));
        if (unread != null) {
            unread.click();
        }
    }
    Thread.sleep(10000);
}
```

I checked this [link](https://libraries.io/search?keywords=browser&languages=C%23) too, to find out if there is another embeddable browser, but I haven't got time to test them all (any recommendation would be appreciated).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay,

I managed to solved this, from the help of this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025165/simulating-a-mousedown-click-mouseup-sequence-in-tampermonkey).
So I changed my js script to this

```
@"(function(x) {
let chatsEl = document.querySelectorAll('.infinite-list-item');
for (let x = 0; x < chatsEl.length; x++) {
    let unread = chatsEl[x].getElementsByClassName('unread');
    if (unread.length > 0) {
        let hoverEvent = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
        hoverEvent.initEvent ('mouseover', true, true);
        unread[0].dispatchEvent (hoverEvent);

        let downEvent = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
        downEvent.initEvent ('mousedown', true, true);
        unread[0].dispatchEvent (downEvent);

        let clickEvent = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
        clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
        unread[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
    }
}
})();";
```

And I managed to click on the unread messages.