# How to simulate typing on contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, cefsharp

Following to my question at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45844533/why-element-click-not-working-in-cefsharp), now I'm stuck with a problem on how to simulate typing in a **contenteditable** div.

The div tag is like below:

```
<div tabindex="-1" class="input-emoji">
    <div class="input-placeholder" style="visibility: visible;">Type a message</div>
    <div class="input" contenteditable="true" data-tab="1" dir="auto" spellcheck="true"></div>
</div>
```

And in order to simulate typing, my code in js is like below:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    try {
        let inputContainerEl = chatPanelEl[0].getElementsByClassName('input-container');
        let input = inputContainerEl[0].getElementsByClassName('input');

        let message = 'Something to type';
        console.log('MESSAGE: ' + message);
        let chars = message.split('');
        for (let n = 0; n < chars.length; n++) {
            let charCode = chars[n].charCodeAt(0);
            console.log('CHAR: ' + chars[n] + ' => CODE: ' + charCode);

            let keypressEvent = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
            keypressEvent.initKeyboardEvent('keypress', true, true, window, false, false, false, false, charCode, charCode);
            input[0].dispatchEvent(keypressEvent);

            let keydownEvent = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
            keydownEvent.initKeyboardEvent('keydown', true, true, window, false, false, false, false, charCode, charCode);
            input[0].dispatchEvent(keydownEvent);

            let keyupEvent = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
            keyupEvent.initKeyboardEvent('keyup', true, true, window, false, false, false, false, charCode, charCode);
            input[0].dispatchEvent(keyupEvent);
        }
    } catch(err) {
        console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
    }
}, 1000);
```

I checked some threads here already, regarding performing **keydown**, **keypress** and **keyup** events from vanilla javascript. But nothing seems to works.

I tried using **selenium** based solution and it works like charm (read the code below)

```
public void run() {
    try {
        WebElement container = driver.findElement(By.className("input-container"));
        if (container != null) {
            WebElement input = container.findElement(By.className("input"));
            if (input != null) {
                input.sendKeys("ECHO: " + this.echo);
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                WebElement submitBtn = driver.findElement(By.className("compose-btn-send"));
                if (submitBtn != null) {
                    submitBtn.click();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But since I'm not able to use selenium (due to project's requirement), I'm forced to use **Cefsharp** instead.

So if anybody knows on how to perform **selenium "sendKeys"** method in vanilla javascript, please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you just want to get/set the contents of the `contenteditable` `div`? Something like `document.getElementById("input").innerHTML` or `document.getElementById("input").textContent` will do that.  Both of these examples are properties that you can also assign to. Or must it be key events?

Comment: Yes ... but I need to trigger keypress so the button for submission could appears ... its a whatsapp web by the way, and I can't just use innerText or append text .... you need to simulate typing...

Answer (score 4):

This solution works for me:

```
element.dispatchEvent(new InputEvent('textInput', {data: keyChar, bubbles: true}));
```

where *element* is contenteditable div and *keyChar* is of course key character ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have a java code as below which can perfrom sendKeys using JavascriptExecutor :-

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\Selenium\\Workplace\\Selenium\\src\\libs\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebElement dd= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='lst-ib' and @name='q']"));
JavascriptExecutor rightexecutor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
rightexecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','yahoo')", dd);
```

Replace your locator(i.e. xpath) in above `JavascriptExecutor` code and convert it into your javascript.

OR

I have found a solution

private void OnIsBrowserInitializedChanged(object sender,

```
IsBrowserInitializedChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if(args.IsBrowserInitialized)
    {
        browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("alert('test');");
    }
}
```

Source :-

[cefsharp execute javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31155779/cefsharp-execute-javascript)

check this out. It having many method :-

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks for the codes... but cannot use selenium based solution as I said in the question... but thanks :)

Comment: Updated my answer. May it help you

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get good results by doing

```
input [0]. textContent = "my text";
```