# Scrapy Splash click button doesn't work

Tags: python, scrapy, splash-js-render

### What I'm trying to do

On avito.ru (Russian real estate site), person's phone is hidden until you click on it. I want to collect the phone using Scrapy+Splash.

Example URL: https://www.avito.ru/moskva/kvartiry/2-k_kvartira_84_m_412_et._992361048

[image: screenshot: Phone is hidden]

After you click the button, pop-up is displayed and phone is visible.

[image]

I'm using Splash [execute](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#execute) API with following Lua script:

```
function main(splash)
    splash:go(splash.args.url)
    splash:wait(10)
    splash:runjs("document.getElementsByClassName('item-phone-button')[0].click()")
    splash:wait(10)
    return splash:png()
end
```

### Problem

The button is not clicked and phone number is not displayed. It's a trivial task, and I have no explanation why it doesn't work.

Click works fine for another field on the same page, if we replace `item-phone-button` with `js-show-stat`. So Javascript *in general* works, and the blue "Display phone" button must be special somehow.

### What I've tried

To isolate the problem, I created a repo with minimal example script and a docker-compose file for Splash:  https://github.com/alexanderlukanin13/splash-avito-phone

Javascript code is valid, you can verify it using Javascript console in Chrome and Firefox

```
document.getElementsByClassName('item-phone-button')[0].click()
```

I've tried it with Splash versions 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, result is the same.

### Update

I've also tried:

- @Lore's suggestions, including `simulateClick()` approach (see [simulate_click](https://github.com/alexanderlukanin13/splash-avito-phone/tree/simulate_click) branch)
- mouseDown/mouseUp events as described here: [Simulating a mousedown, click, mouseup sequence in Tampermonkey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025165/simulating-a-mousedown-click-mouseup-sequence-in-tampermonkey) (see [trigger_mouse_event](https://github.com/alexanderlukanin13/splash-avito-phone/tree/trigger_mouse_event) branch)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following script works for me:

```
function main(splash, args)
  splash.private_mode_enabled = false
  assert(splash:go(args.url))
  btn = splash:select_all('.item-phone-button')[2]
  btn:mouse_click()
  btn.style.border = "5px solid black"
  assert(splash:wait(0.5))
  return {
    num = #splash:select_all('.item-phone-button'),
    html = splash:html(),
    png = splash:png(),
    har = splash:har(),
  }
end
```

There were 2 issues with the original solution:

1. There are 2 elements with 'item-phone-button' class, and button of interest is the second one. I've checked which element is matched by setting `btn.style.border = "5px solid black"`.
2. This website requires private mode to be disabled, likely because it uses localStorage. Check http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#website-is-not-rendered-correctly for other common suggestions.

Comment: Actually, just adding `splash.private_mode_enabled = false` to the original script does the job. Thanks Mike!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your implementation works, but I suggest to rename `main` with `parse`, the default function called by spiders on start.

If this isn't the problem, first thing to do is controlling if you have picked the right element of that class using Javascript with css selector. Maybe it exists another item with `item-phone-button` class attribute and you are clicking in the wrong place.

If all above is correct, I suggest then two options that worked for me:

Using [Splash mouse_click](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-ref.html#splash-mouse-click) and [Splash wait](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-ref.html#splash-wait) (the latter I see you have already used). If it don't work, try double click, by substituting in your code:

```
local button = splash:select('item phone-button') 
button:mouse_click()
button:mouse_click()
```

Using [Splash wait_for_resume](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-ref.html#splash-wait-for-resume), that executes javascript code until terminated and then restart LUA. Your code will become simpler too:

```
function main(splash)
    splash:go(splash.args.url)
    splash:wait_for_resume("document.getElementsByClassName([[
                  function main(splash) {
                       document.getElementsByClassName('item-phone-button');[0].click()
                       splash.resume();
                  }               
    ]])
    return splash:png()
end
```

EDIT: it seems that is good to use `dispatchEvent` instead of `click()` like in [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events):

```
function simulateClick() {
  var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
    view: window,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
  });
  var cb = document.getElementById('checkbox'); 
  var cancelled = !cb.dispatchEvent(event);
  if (cancelled) {
    // A handler called preventDefault.
    alert("cancelled");
  } else {
    // None of the handlers called preventDefault.
    alert("not cancelled");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it makes sense and I upvote it. Unfortunately, non of these advises works in my case. I suspect that there is a compatibility issue between Splash's Webkit version and this particular site.

Comment: thank you. take a look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: FTR, splash:mouse_click is better than any JS-based click function (via MouseEvent, etc.), because it sends a real mouse click event to the browser window.