# Get content loaded dynamically on mouseclick using Scrapy Splash and Lua

Tags: python, lua, scrapy, mouseclick-event, dynamic-content

I have a Scrapy Splash scraper with Lua script.
The Lua script currently only initiates scrolling on a page to load more results on the search page.
From the search page I navigate to detail pages which I scrape.
However, on the detail page the photo carousel is not present in the DOM yet, it's loaded dynamically when the user clicks the `#showphotos` element.

After clicking that element the following photocarousel HTML is loaded:

```
<div id="slider">
    <div class="slider-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="https://www.example.com/images/1.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="https://www.example.com/images/2.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I already checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54048624/scrapy-splash-click-on-a-button-then-get-content-from-new-page-in-new-window) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49276401/scrapy-splash-click-button-doesnt-work).

So I tried writing some script:

```
click_script = """
        function main(splash, args)

            btn = splash:select_all('#showphotos')[0]
            btn:mouse_click()
            assert(splash:wait(0.5))
              return {
                num = #splash:select_all('#slider div.slider-inner'),
                html = splash:html()
              }
        end
        """
```

As I'm very new to Splash and Lua I don't know where to add this code or where to call it from.

I've created a test detail page [here](https://www.toptrouwen.nl/test).

My current code:

**myscraper.py**

```
import json
import re

import scrapy
import time
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from myresults.items import MyResultItem


class Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myscraper'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.example.com/results']

    def start_requests(self):
        # lua script for scroll to bottom while all objects appeared
        lua_script = """
        function main(splash, args)
          local object_count = 0
          local url = splash.args.url
          splash:go(url)
          splash:wait(0.5)
          local get_object_count = splash:jsfunc([[
            function (){
              var objects = document.getElementsByClassName("object-adres");
              return objects.length;
            }
            ]])
          temp_object_count = get_object_count()
          local retry = 3
          while object_count ~= temp_object_count do
            splash:evaljs('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);')
            splash:wait(0.5)
            object_count = temp_object_count
            temp_object_count = get_object_count()
            
          end
          return splash:html()
        end
        """

        # yield first splash request with lua script and parse it from parse def
        yield SplashRequest(
            self.start_urls[0], self.parse,
            endpoint='execute',
            args={'lua_source': lua_script},
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        # get all properties from first page which was generated with lua script
        # get all adreslink from a tag
        object_links = response.css('a.adreslink::attr(href)').getall()
        for link in object_links:
            # send request with each link and parse it from parse_object def
            yield scrapy.Request(link, self.parse_object)

    def parse_object(self, response):
        # create new MyResultItem which will saved to json file
        item = MyResultItem()

        item['url'] = response.url # get url        
        


        yield item
```

**items.py**

```
import scrapy

class RentalItem(scrapy.Item):
    id = scrapy.Field()
    photos = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()

    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

The Lua script runs like a Python script. In `Spider -> start_requests -> lua_script` you already have a Lua script. You want to select the first `#showphotos` element and click it; also, you want to add more data to the results.

As such, after executing the already-existing Lua code, we want to tell Splash to select the first `#showphotos` element:

```lua
btn = splash:select_all('#showphotos')[1]
```

*Please note the index **1**, not 0, because the `splash:select_all` array starts from 1.*

After that, click it:

```lua
btn:mouse_click()
```

And in the end, add more data to the results:

```lua
return {
    num = splash:select_all('#slider div.slider-inner')[1].node.outerHTML,
    html = splash:html()
}
```

*Again, please note the index **1**, not 0, because the `splash:select_all` array starts from 1. Also, I have added `.node.outerHTML` because `splash:select_all()` returns a Lua object, and there is no default way to serialize it to JSON ([ref](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash/issues/557#issuecomment-273245797))*

Finally, you should end up with something like this:

```lua
function main(splash, args)
  local object_count = 0
  local url = splash.args.url
  splash:go(url)
  splash:wait(0.5)

  local get_object_count = splash:jsfunc([[
    function (){
      var objects = document.getElementsByClassName("object-adres");
      return objects.length;
    }
  ]])
  temp_object_count = get_object_count()
  local retry = 3
  while object_count ~= temp_object_count do
    splash:evaljs('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);')
    splash:wait(0.5)
    object_count = temp_object_count
    temp_object_count = get_object_count()
  end

  btn = splash:select_all('#showphotos')[1]
  btn:mouse_click()
  assert(splash:wait(0.5))
  
  return {
    num = splash:select_all('#slider div.slider-inner')[1].node.outerHTML,
    html = splash:html()
  }
end
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'll try that.

What I do not understand yet in your solution is that the first part of the Lua script is relevant for a search overview page e.g. `/allcompanies` to scroll down to show all results.
The 2nd part of the Lua script with your suggested code to mouseclick on `#showphotos` element is only relevant for detail pages that have a photo carousel, e.g.: `company/1443/apple`,`company/8233/msft`,`company/1413/google`.
If I wrap everything in a single function `function main(splash, args)` as it is proposed now, I'm executing the script unnecessarily a lot of times?

Comment: ps. I also updated my test example page to show what I mean