# Unable to click button in Lua Script with Splash

Tags: lua, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

This problem is similar in nature [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49276401/scrapy-splash-click-button-doesnt-work), yet my problem still persists after having attempted the provided solution.

I want my Lua script to react to a modal popup in the case that it appears by closing it. However, the final screenshot, keeps showing the modal pop-up thus indicating that it has not been closed.

This is the initial link from which I want to scrape from: 'https://www.goodreads.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query='

And here is my Lua script:

```
function main(splash, args)
  splash.private_mode_enabled = false
  splash:set_user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0")
  assert(splash:go(args.url))
  assert(splash:wait(0.5))

  input_box = assert(splash:select('#search_query_main'))
  input_box:focus()
  input_box:send_text("dostoevsky")
  input_box:send_keys("<Enter>")
  assert(splash:wait(1)) 

  if not splash:select('div.modal--centered div.modal__close') == nil then
    close_button = splash:select('div.modal--centered div.modal__close > button')
    close_button.style.border = "5px solid black"
    close_button:mouse_click()
  end
  splash:wait(1)

  return {
    num_modal = #splash:select_all('div.modal--centered div.modal__close'),
    num_close_btns = #splash:select_all('div.modal--centered div.modal__close > button'),
    html = splash:html(),
    png = splash:png(),
  }
end
```

The function returns **num_close_btns:** *1* and **num_modal:** *1* thus suggesting that my css-selectors are fine so I can only assume that the mouse_click event is not doing what I expect it to do.

[image: Screenshot of modal popup]

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me. I don't know why removing "if" works:

```
function main(splash, args)
  splash.private_mode_enabled = false
  splash:set_user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0")
  assert(splash:go(args.url))
  assert(splash:wait(0.5))

  input_box = assert(splash:select('#search_query_main'))
  input_box:focus()
  input_box:send_text("dostoevskykqj")
  input_box:send_keys("<Enter>")
  assert(splash:wait(3)) 
    
  close_button = splash:select('div.modal--centered div.modal__close > button')
  close_button.style.border = "5px solid black"
  close_button:mouse_click()
  splash:wait(1)

  return {
    num_modal = #splash:select_all('div.modal--centered div.modal__close'),
    num_close_btns = #splash:select_all('div.modal--centered div.modal__close > button'),
    html = splash:html(),
    png = splash:png(),
  }
end
```