# How to simulate a *real* mouse click on element in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

`$(selector).click()` results in nothing happening.
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52549234) works in the browser console with the javascript context set to the iframe, but not the main page:

`simulateMouseClick($("iframe").contents().find(selector))`

results in:

> Uncaught TypeError: targetNode.dispatchEvent is not a function
>      at triggerMouseEvent (:5:20)
>      at :8:9
>      at Array.forEach ()
>      at simulateMouseClick (:7:52)
>      at :1:1

`$("iframe").contents().find(selector).text()` gives me what's expected so it's the correct element.

how can I achieve this?

Edit: adding this as people apparently can't read:
`$("iframe").contents().find(selector).click()`
has absolutely no effect as `.click()` does not simulate a REAL mouse click.

Answer (score 2):

**With jQuery :**

```
$("iframe").contents().find(selector).click();
```

**With Vannila JS :**

Using window.frames gives you access to the iframes' window object, as mentionned in the [Mozilla doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frames)

You can use this object to find elements in the iframe and use them in your script. For example :

```
  var iframeWindow = window.frames[0];
  var element = iframeWindow.document.getElementsByClassName("selector")[0];
  element.click();
```

Comment: someone clearly barely read the question, I have no problem getting the element, a simple `.click()` does not work, it has absolutely no effect, the only method I've found that does isn't working when done from the main page.

Comment: I just tried with Vanilla JS by replacing the element.click() with simulateMouseClick(element) to click on a link in an iframe, and it works. I am pretty sure you could also do it in jQuery with simulateMouseClick($("iframe").contents().find(selector)[0]) . But even though it might not be "real" click,  .click() should at least trigger the click event.
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FX9452XNM1SB
May be you have other issues ? Are you dealing with crossdomain iframes or do you have several libraries loaded (jquery and prototype for example).

Answer (score 0):

Get the element inside your jQuery Object, and use the vanillaJS `.click()` method:

```
$("iframe").contents().find(selector)[0].click();
```

That's it.

PS: I know this is an old question, but I had the same problem and solved it that way :)