# Click function is not working on a button

Tags: javascript

I try to create an application to log in to https://www.easports.com/fifa/ultimate-team/web-app/# using JS, and I am not able to click on the Login button.

Calling click on the button element.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].click()
```

Nothing happens. If I move with the mouse and click it, it works.

Comment: If you check devtools->Listeners, you will understand that the button listen for event 'mousedown', and there are also some checks for e.clientX e.clientY.
You need a bit of debugging the listener handler in order to achieve what you want to.

You could create and dispatch event by checking this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025165/simulating-a-mousedown-click-mouseup-sequence-in-tampermonkey

By the way again there are checks/logic which you need to understand.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks a lot idmitrov. I've managed to make it work using this:

```
var targetNode = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
if (targetNode) {
    //--- Simulate a natural mouse-click sequence.
    triggerMouseEvent (targetNode, "mouseover");
    triggerMouseEvent (targetNode, "mousedown");
    triggerMouseEvent (targetNode, "mouseup");
    triggerMouseEvent (targetNode, "click");
}
else
    console.log ("*** Target node not found!");

function triggerMouseEvent (node, eventType) {
    var clickEvent = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent (eventType, true, true);
    node.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```

Comment: Please accept my answer and upvote since this is what i originally posted and got downvoted. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It looks like they are using `mousedown` and `mouseup` event listeners to determine if both events occurred while the cursor is over the button. This is an example of of a button that doesn't want to be clicked automatically using a script.