# How to make a new button to start embedded Google Slides presentation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-slides

I have a Google Slides presentation embedded on my website in an iframe. I want to create a separate button (large and visible), that starts it.

I tried running `$(".goog-flat-button[title='Play']").click();` in the Chrome console - no effect. Am I targeting a wrong element, or should this not work in an iframe (*why not?*), or am I doing something inherently wrong?

[image]

Comment: please can you put a working code base so that someone can help you

Comment: I guess your website and the slide's domain are different. Then you won't be able to, due to security aspects (cross site scripting)

Comment: @casenonsensitive Than makes sense, thank you. However, at some point, it should be all just HTML in the user's browser, that could be manipulated with JS - or is it not?

Comment: Imagine you have a frame with a payment provider and you can just manipulate the content. The user thinks they are signing a transaction for 1$ and you just change it to 2$

Comment: @casenonsensitive That makes sense, too, but not the case here. See the solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

If you inspect closely the play button doesn't listen for click events directly:

[image]

It does listen to different mouse events. Using this [snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24026594) you can successfully simulate the mouse behavior when clicking on the button and finally triggering the wanted behavior.

```
var targetNode = document.querySelector (".goog-flat-button[title='Play']");
if (targetNode) {
    //--- Simulate a natural mouse-click sequence.
    triggerMouseEvent (targetNode, "mouseover");
    triggerMouseEvent (targetNode, "mousedown");
    triggerMouseEvent (targetNode, "mouseup");
    triggerMouseEvent (targetNode, "click");
}
else
    console.error ("*** Target node not found!");

function triggerMouseEvent (node, eventType) {
    var clickEvent = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent (eventType, true, true);
    node.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```