# Why does the click event of JavaScript not working?

Tags: javascript, scripting

I got this link from a friend of mine for testing my reaction time.
https://www.arealme.com/reaction-test/en/

This is a game where a red circle will appear and after random time it will turn green. I need to click as soon as it turns green. That is my reaction time.

With real reaction, my best score is 178, in case you don't believe I have attached ss [image]

I know I can edit this 178 to any number I want.
But I wanted to create a script that generated the click event as soon as the green circle appears.

I have planned to call the below function with setInterval

```
const clickCircle = (className)=> {
    let greenCircles = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    if(greenCircles && greenCircles.length){
        greenCircles[0].click();
    }else{
        console.log("No circles found with name ", className)
    }
}

clickCircle("tfny-circleGreen");
```

The name of the class containing the green circle is tfny-circleGreen. So calling clickCircle("tfny-circleGreen") should generate a click event. But it's not.

What am I missing?

Maybe they have overridden the click function. If that's the case, how do I restore it?

Please don't ask why I want this, it's just I wanted to try it this way for fun.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you have posted no code, and it is unclear why you are trying to do what you are trying to do

Comment: Have you tried using a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)? You need to create an observer and attach it to the container which holds the green circle. And as soon as it appears your observer will "fire".

Comment: Please consider both removing irrelevant information, and adding relevant information.

Comment: Also, to fix you `click()` not working, use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24026594/3258251) method instead.

Comment: I have added a code which I have written to add click functionality @ControlAltDel

Comment: Thank you, it worked @decho

Answer (score 0):

```html
function triggerMouseEvent (node, eventType) {
    var clickEvent = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent (eventType, true, true);
    node.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}

const clickCircle = (className)=> {
    let greenCircles = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    if(greenCircles && greenCircles.length){
        triggerMouseEvent (greenCircles[0], "mouseover");
        triggerMouseEvent (greenCircles[0], "mousedown");
        triggerMouseEvent (greenCircles[0], "mouseup");
        triggerMouseEvent(greenCircles[0], "click");
    }else{
        console.log("No circles found with name ", className)
    }
}

setInterval(()=> {
    clickCircle("tfny-circleGreen");
}, 10)
```

This is the complete code that works :D

The click() function was not working so I had to simulate it.