# How to click and hold in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, puppeteer

I am trying to click and hold using Puppeteer. I tried using `page.click` inside a `while` loop but it didn't work.

```
let browserURL = `http://127.0.0.1:9222`;

let browser = await puppeteer.connect({ browserURL, defaultViewport: null });

const page = await browser.newPage();
while (pageContent.includes("hold")) {
  await page.click("div")
}
```

I also tried this:

```
await page.mouse.click(132, 103, { button: 'left' })
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: I believe that you can use [mouse.down](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v10.1.0&show=api-mousedownoptions) and [mouse.up](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v10.1.0&show=api-mouseupoptions). I've never tried it myself though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few tools to trigger a mouse hold in Puppeteer: [`page.click`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v10.0.0/docs/api.md#pageclickselector-options), [`mouse.click`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v10.0.0/docs/api.md#mouseclickx-y-options), [`mouse.down`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v10.0.0/docs/api.md#mousedownoptions) and [`mouse.up`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v10.0.0/docs/api.md#mouseupoptions). [`page.hover`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v10.0.0/docs/api.md#pagehoverselector) can be useful for positioning the mouse over a selector and [`mouse.move`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v10.0.0/docs/api.md#mousemovex-y-options) can be useful for coordinate-based positioning and implementing clicking-and-dragging.

Then, there's [`page.evaluate`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v10.0.0/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) (and family), which lets you run browser code to [trigger native `mousedown` and `mouseup` events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20567748/how-to-trigger-a-onmousedown-event-manually-from-javascript-not-jquery-on-a-em) on the target element. If you have difficulty clicking with the Puppeteer functions (for example, due to [visibility issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66537619/6243352)), `evaluate` is a good next option to try.

Which approach you choose depends on your use case. If you use a `.click()` call (these are convenience wrappers on `page.hover`, `mouse.move()`, `mouse.down()` annd `mouse.up()`), you'll want to set the `delay` property on the options object to simulate the hold, which the docs describe as

> `delay` <number> Time to wait between mousedown and mouseup in milliseconds. Defaults to 0.

Here's a proof of concept on the following button:

```js
const hms = () => ("" + Date()).slice(16, 24);
const btnEl = document.querySelector("button");
btnEl.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
  document.querySelector("ul").innerHTML +=
    `<li>mousedown at ${hms()}</li>`
  ;
});
btnEl.addEventListener("mouseup", e => {
  document.querySelector("ul").innerHTML +=
    `<li>mouseup at ${hms()}</li>`
  ;
});
```

```html
<button>click and hold me</button>
<ul></ul>
```

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

let browser;
(async () => {
  const html = `
    <button>click and hold me</button>
    <ul></ul>
    <script>
      const hms = () => ("" + Date()).slice(16, 24);
      const btnEl = document.querySelector("button");
      btnEl.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
        document.querySelector("ul").innerHTML +=
          \`<li>mousedown at \${hms()}</li>\`
        ;
      });
      btnEl.addEventListener("mouseup", e => {
        document.querySelector("ul").innerHTML +=
          \`<li>mouseup at \${hms()}</li>\`
        ;
      });
    </script>
  `;
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html);
  await page.click("button", {delay: 5000});
  await page.waitForFunction(() => 
    document.querySelector("ul").innerText.includes("mouseup")
  );
  console.log(await page.$eval("ul", el => el.innerText));
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close())
;
```

Output is something like

```
mousedown at 12:53:23
mouseup   at 12:53:28
```

which shows that the mouse was held down on the button for 5 seconds.